# How to simulate a slow internet connection for testing a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, localhost

I am working on a prototype website on **localhost** using **NodeJS** and **MongoDB**.

I want to see how my site will load on slow internet.

How can I **replicate that with localhost**?

Comment: Most modern browser allow you to simulate a slow connection in the developer tools. For example Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Throttling

Comment: If you are testing using google chrome, this might be helpful: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#throttle

Answer (score 6):

If you use google chrome, press F12, go to `Network` and go to `online` and select some speed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If this is a localhost web page, and you want to know how long does it take to process and render the HTML web page, you can see via :

- Go to the Developer Tools
- Go to the Network tab.
- Just navigate to the URL you want to check the timing for. Suppose, for your default.html page. You can just click on the hyperlink to go to that page
- Networking tab will capture all of the requests in front of you, with their links, their HTTP status, their timeline etc.
- The last link which will be downloaded will show the time elapsed in loading your website's web page.

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome dev tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#throttle) will help you to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Iam using a mac and this one's working perfect

https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/throttle/

Install using npm (need sudo)

```
sudo npm install @sitespeed.io/throttle -g
```

Then add some entries to the conf file in etc directory (check their documentation from the above link)

Now simply choose your speed

```
throttle --up 56 --down 256 --rtt 200
```

I use this crazy speed to see my mobile app's progressbar animations sometimes